# Indirect Addressing in Brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

How would I move the memory pointer to a location described in a memory cell? Super confused.

So if cell 4 is 10, how would I set the memory pointer to 10 given the address of cell 4. Absolutely no idea where to start.

I figured something out using a [>] where all cells were 0 between the two cells, but otherwise I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement some sort of memory model for your program. Brainfuck does not support indirect addressing. But since it is turing complete, it definitely is possible to do whatever.

You're thinking along the wrong lines. You want to simulate indirect addressing in bf. Before you can do that, you need to think about simulating RAM in the first place. I.e. even direct addressing is a problem. You can't just access "the 5th memory location" unless you know exactly where you are, which you don't always know if you're not extremely careful... because it's brainfuck

You might want to take a look at some C to brainfuck projects floating around. They do a similar sort of thing.